# laravel query builder search all fields

Tags: laravel, laravel-query-builder

Guys I need to have a filter that validates in all fields with orWhere, for example: users? Search = Jhon he has to check that there is jhon in the name, email ....
Has anyone done this?
thankful

Comment: You likely need to use a combination of orWhere() statements with mysql like operators.

User::query()->where('name', 'like', '%JHon%')->orWhere('email', 'like', '%JHon%')->get();

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far... for better clarification

Comment: Ok, but not exist function exact ? exemple search .. ?

Answer (score 0):

Same with other answer, you should use multiple orWhere() to do that
Here is the sample

```
$search = 'Jhon';
$conditions = ['name', 'email'];                          
$data = User::where(function ($query) use ($conditions, $search) {
    foreach ($conditions as $column)                                
        $query->orWhere($column, 'like', '%' . $search . '%');      
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You Can get this type.

> $query = User::query();
>
> $columns = ['name', 'surname', 'address'];
>
> foreach($columns as $column){
>
> $query->orWhere($column, 'LIKE', '%' . $input . '%');
>
> }
>
> $users = $query->get();